# How to get the distributor for a specific publication?

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

Hi I have several servers that have publications, and some of these servers 
use different distributors,
 and in the distributor server, I have several distributor databases.

How can I find out what is the distributor server and distributor database
for a specific Database      that I know is published?

I am using sql server 2008 r2,
and I am currently using the stored procedure: EXEC sp_get_distributor

thanks and regards
marcelo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run [sp_helpdistributor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177504.aspx) in the publication database.